# trying to submit a collection of "buttons-checkbox"

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have fallen in love with twitter-bootstrap and I like the simple style I can use for my applications.

I would like to use the element **buttons-checkbox** instead of a regular **checkbox**.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-small" value="1" id="LanguagesAvailable_0__Code" name="LanguagesAvailable[0].Code">
                Value 1
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-small" value="2" id="LanguagesAvailable_1__Code" name="LanguagesAvailable[1].Code">
                Value 2
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-small" value="3" id="LanguagesAvailable_2__Code" name="LanguagesAvailable[2].Code">
                Value 3
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-small" value="4" id="LanguagesAvailable_3__Code" name="LanguagesAvailable[3].Code">
                Value 4
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sadly, I can post those types of elements.

Is there any work-around to style my checkboxes with twitter-bootstrap and POST those elements to a FORM?

I've prepared a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/6n2HE/1/).

Comment: Is this something like what you're looking for (I didn't make this btw - just Googled it): http://jsfiddle.net/charettes/SauLj/

Comment: Thanks Billy, I have seen that but it seems that it's not fully supported yet https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1161

Comment: @LeftyX It's not supported by or integrated into Bootstrap, but you can still use it in your project as it does achieve the behavior you're looking for. As indicated by the issue you linked, there is no "supported" solution.

Comment: @BillyMoat: I have used your solution. If you answer my question I will accept it.

Comment: @LeftyX - I've posted it as an answer below, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/charettes/SauLj/

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#radio_3').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#radio_2').prop('checked', true);
});
```

CSS:

```
.btn-group > input {
    display: none;
}

.btn-group input:first-child + .btn {
     /* This is an actual copy/paste of the .btn-group .btn:first-child style */
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

input:checked + label.btn {
    /* This is an actual copy/paste of the .btn:active style */
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    outline: 0 none;
}

input[disabled] + label.btn {
    /* This is an actual copy/paste of the .btn:disabled style */
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.65;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" id="single_checkbox" />
<label class="btn" for="single_checkbox">Single</label>
<br/><br/>
<div class="btn-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" />
    <label class="btn" for="checkbox_1">Checkbox one</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_2" />
    <label class="btn" for="checkbox_2">Checkbox two</label>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled id="checkbox_3" />
    <label class="btn" for="checkbox_3">Disabled checkbox three</label>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="btn-group">
    <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio_1" />
    <label class="btn" for="radio_1">Radio one</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio_2" />
    <label class="btn" for="radio_2">Radio two</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio_3" />
    <label class="btn" for="radio_3">Disabled radio three</label>
</div>
```